# How to get data from a Lua table except nil

Tags: debugging, lua, lua-table

I'm trying to recieve data from a pretty big table (`bigTable`) and the `getRow` function should rearrange some data for faster calculation (specific information below). The problem is that some of this values don't exist (-->are `nil`). I thought I'd taken care of this by adding the `if-Statement` to check first if the value does even exist, but I still get the error below. Thanks for your help.

My function (from line 46):

```
function getRow(a, b)
    row = {}
    for d = 0, 3 do
        if (bigTable[a + d][b + d]) then
            table.insert(row, bigTable[a + d][b + d])
        end
    end
    return row
end
```

Error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua.exe: .\solution_11.lua:49: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        .\solution_11.lua:49: in function 'getRow'
        .\solution_11.lua:69: in function 'diagonal'
        .\solution_11.lua:89: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

> The `getRow()`-function should get the values of the two dimensional array from point A, B "diagonally" downwards.

Comment: try `if a and b and type(bigTable[a + d])=='table' and bigTable[a + d][b + d] then`

Comment: Yes this worked for me! Thank you very much. Do you want to explain this attempt further and post it as an answer to help me and other people to understand what you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal can be achieved by exchanging this line

```
if (bigTable[a + d][b + d]) then
```

with this line

```
if a and b and type(bigTable[a + d])=='table' and bigTable[a + d][b + d] then
```

This solves the problem because every possibility is checked (`a` or `b` can't be `nil`, the table you trying to access is even existent and it contains the value you trying to access). You only checked for the last one and therefore you got an error when the value was `nil`.